# How to make the map full screen with tab navigation? - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

My main container is set up to have half google maps and the other half to be my tab screens. But when I click on the bottom navigation map button, I would like it to cover the full screen instead of half like it does with the other screen? I'm new to react native and personally don't know how to implement this. Any help would be amazing!

**MainContainer.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import FloatingButton from './components/FloatingButton';



import DetailScreen from './screens/DetailScreen';
import MapScreen from './screens/MapScreen';
import SettingScreen from './screens/SettingScreen';

const detailsName = 'details';
const mapName = 'Map';
const settingsName = 'Settings';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();



export default function MainContainer({ navigation }) {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer independent={true}>

            <FloatingButton
                style={styles.floatinBtn}
                onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />

            <MapView style={{ flex: 0.55 }} />


            <Tab.Navigator style={styles.Tab_Container}>

                <Tab.Screen name={detailsName}
                    component={DetailScreen} />

                <Tab.Screen name={mapName}
                    component={MapScreen} />

                <Tab.Screen name={settingsName}
                    component={SettingScreen} />

            </Tab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Tab_Container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },

    floatinBtn: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 10,
        left: 5,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to add a boolean variable using useState to change the flex dimension of your map component from 0.55 to 1.
To do that you have to declare a variable like that:

```
const [fullscreen, setFullscreen]= useState(false)
```

and use it inside your map component style:

```
<MapView style={{flex: fullscreen? 1: 0.55 } />
```

To trigger it, inside the button of your map, for onPress method you have to change the state of the fullscreen variable:

```
<YourButton onPress={()=>setFullscreen(!fullscreen)}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply and this does seem like it would word, but I forgot to mention that it isn't a button by itself, its a bottom navigation button, and I don't thing you're able to add 'onPress={()=>setFullscreen(!fullscreen)}' within the tab.screens

Comment: Check this link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabpress
You can add to your component the listener tabPress to trigger the change fullscreen  variable